# How to call RESTful Store APIs of WSO2 APIM 2.1 which have scope after importing the swagger file?

Tags: rest, authentication, wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

I have created a RESTful API for all the WSO2 store APIs by using the swagger definition. (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/v6.1.66/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store/src/main/resources/store-api.yaml)
The GET call which does not require any scope, can be called easily from the Stores API console but when trying to call the APIs which have the (apim:subscribe) scope I get "Unauthenticated Request".

NOTE: I am able to use the curl commands to access the STORE APIs by creating tokens but here I am trying to use the swagger file to publish the Store APIs. I have noticed that in the store under the Application-> Production Keys -> Scope there is the apim:subscribe scope available after I've created this API via the swagger file but even when I try to access the APIs using this scope, I still get the "Unauthenticated Request" error.
Can someone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: do you have a role assigned to the scope?

Comment: @gusto2 yup as per the swagger file the role "Internal/subscriber" is assigned to apim:subscribe and also I have logged into the store via admin to use the API console and I also checked that admin has this role assigned to it.

Comment: when you regenerate the application token,  does the console state it has the requested scope? (usually it's openid, default and am_application)

Comment: @gusto2 yes it does. The scope changes from default to apim:subscribe also if I use default scope tokens I get a "The access token does not allow you to access the requested resource" error but when I change that to apim:subscribe I get "Unauthenticated request".

Comment: I basically just imported the default swagger definition, nothing else so nothing different or extra done. Im just wondering how this is supposed to work, because for other APIs which do not have any Authentication we can simply use the endpoints directly and WSO2 apim only provides basic auth and digest auth for the endpoints, but in case of STORE RESTful APIs we require scope specific tokens to access the URLs and then when these APIs are published in WSO2 they will also need the application tokens as well or are just scope tokens generated from the store sufficient to call these STORE APIs?

Comment: Store generates an "application token", so check if the resource allows an application token or a user token is required

Comment: Yes I checked that as well. X-auth-type is set to Application and Application User, x-throttling-tier is set to unlimited and x-scope is apim:subscribe for those of the required scopes. These came by default when importing the swagger file.

Answer (score 0):

The Swagger specification has a Security Definitions Object:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-definitions-object

Once you configure it correctly you will have some new elements in the UI, you should see the Authorize button on the top left, and to the right of each action that requires authentication you should see a lock. 
[image]

See the petstore demo: 
http://petstore.swagger.io/

Here are a few more examples:

- http://turoapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index 

  This one has an API Key Authentication
- http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index

  This one has an OAuth2 Implicit Grant

Comment: Im am currently using WSO2 APIM 2.1 and when I create a REST API (Store APIs) using the swagger definition, I am unable to access the scope-specific API calls because for some reason the scope seems to not match. When viewed in the WSO2 APIM Store, there is no lock button to authorize anything so I cannot seem to figure out what exactly is going wrong with these scoped tokens.

Comment: That is because your swagger definition does not have any authentication (Security Definitions Object) defined,   you must configure it correctly if you want the request to work

Comment: Yes, the problem is more related to the Access tokens which require specific scopes. (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/#guide). When publishing the STORE APIs in WSO2, the REST API is not able to make calls to those contexts which require a SCOPE to be defined in the header (The endpoints require scope specific token whereas WSO2 requires default scope access tokens) so not sure how they both work together when the swagger definition is used to publish them in WSO2.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think we are understanding each other, I'm saying that your problem is in your swagger definition (store-api.yaml) unless you define your security there that definition is useless

Comment: Sorry about that, Im not so well-versed with Swagger but if you could maybe elaborate a bit. I understood that you meant that the swagger file provided by WSO2 APIM is not correct and I am missing out on some part of the security. Currently, the file has the below JSON

"x-wso2-security" : {
    "apim" : {
      "x-wso2-scopes" : [ {
        "description" : "",
        "roles" : "Internal/subscriber",
        "name" : "apim:subscribe",
        "key" : "apim:subscribe"
      } ]
    }
  }

should I add "type": "oauth2" and a few other attributes to it ?

Comment: I was under the assumption that everything would be defined by WSO2 APIM in the swagger file and not much modification would be required on it.

Comment: @LenGomes If you are using swagger, you should get familiar with the OpenAPI-Specification... and those `"x-wso2-..."` are not standard ... I will update my post with a few more examples using security and showing how it looks in the swagger-ui

Comment: ...and if the swagger file is provided to you by WSO2 APIM and you have no control over it, you need to get to the bottom of who creates that file, anyone running swagger codegen against your (store-api.yaml) will run into the same issue `"Unauthenticated Request"`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was wondering since it looked pretty different from the example you provided. I raised a ticket with WSO2 (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-6093) to have this looked at.

Comment: @LeGo Good, Ultimately the are the authority on everything WSO2 no one better to resolve that issue... But in the mid time you should manually build a store-api.yaml with Security Definitions to get yourself familiar with swagger